# Confusion in integration by substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution, line-integrals

I have a following line integral along curve $l$:

$$\int f(l) \dfrac{dx}{dl}dl$$

Here $\dfrac{dx}{dl}$ denotes the $x$-axis direction cosine of element $dl.$

Now by substitution, the integral becomes:

$$\int f(l) dx$$

Now since $dl$ has disappeared, along what curve are we integrating?

Comment: You're now integrating along the $x$ axis, which is also a 'curve'

Comment: You'll have to provide a lot more information than this, it's just as ambiguous to us

Comment: @caverac: Are we integrating along the projection of curve on $x$-axis?

Comment: You’re integrating with respect to the variable $x$.  
Now, in order to do that (and make sense of your final integral), you need to express the function $f(l)$ in terms of the variable $x$.  That is, a function $g$ mapping $f(l)$ to the variable $x$ must exist, such that $g(f(l))=x$, and $f(l)=g^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: Substitutions involve derivatives of actual functions. You did not define $dx\over dl$ in this way. Before the substitution is justifiable, you need to come up with an interpretation of $dx \over dl$ as a derivative of some function $x$ with respect to "$l$" that still provides the interpretation you've offered. Your big problem is that $dl$ is a vector. Which by the way also means that $\int ... dl$ is not properly called a "line integral", because that refers to integral with respect to arclength, not vector integration. The proper notation for a line integral is $|dl|$ or $ds$.